# css custom cursor not working

Tags: html, css

I am using the css custom cursor to use an image for the cursor. The image doesn't work. What is wrong with this code?
[Here](http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com/pics/TREES.jpg) is the image used. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/ecfqkfx1/)

```
 cursor: url('http://www.sarkelliancreed.comule.com/pics/TREES.jpg'), auto;
```

Comment: Post the full code. Have you wrapped it inside a class or id?

Comment: The only element on the page is a `<header>`. It is not inside anything.

Comment: Do you really attempt to use that huge image as a cursor?

Comment: can u show the entire code.  There may be other css properties taking precedence over the cursor property

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was dealing with this problem last night. The issue is that there is a limit to the size of the image you can use as a cursor. If you really need an image that large to follow the cursor, have a div with that image snap to the cursor position on the mousemove event.

MDN at least describes the size limit for Firefox:

> In Gecko (Firefox) the limit of the cursor size is 128×128px. Larger cursor images are ignored. However, you should limit yourself to the size 32×32 for maximum compatibility with operating systems and platforms.

[MDN documentation for cursor property in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor#url)

Put in a 32x32 png rather than the image you're using as the URL and run the Fiddle again, and it works. Example image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1d/Smile_icon_32x32.png

Comment: What an avatar to have for this question.

Comment: Just to future-proof @ManojKumar's comment, JHS's avatar is currently a cursor arrow.

Comment: Chrome is reporting for my 128px wide cursor "[Deprecation] Custom cursors with size greater than 32x32 DIP intersecting native UI is deprecated and will be removed in M75, around June 2019. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5825971391299584 for more details.", and sure enough when the cursor is near the edge of the viewport it falls back to the default.

Answer (score -3):

Any type of file format won't work, only `.cur` files.

```
cursor: url('http://www.sarkelliancreed.comule.com/pics/TREES.cur'), auto;
```

source: https://fb.watch/dRdLF-vwD2/

Comment: Don't believe everything you see on some random Facebook video, rather look up the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor#url

Comment: it works and I tested it out, just don't make your file pixel size too big under 20px, why not try it on yourself?